# C# How do I allow a user to enter instance variables and create multiple objects?

Tags: c#, class, loops, object, instance-variables

I am trying to create a program that asks the user "how many player's details would you like to enter?" after they enter this the user is then asked to enter in each of the attributes of these players.

Essentially, I am trying to get the user to instantiate multiple objects of a class.

This is what I have entered into the FootBallPlayer class

```
class FootballPlayer
{
  private string fullName;
  private int yearBorn;
  private double goalsPerGame;

  // constructor
  public FootballPlayer (string name, int year, double goals)

  {
     fullName = name;
     yearBorn = year;
     goalsPerGame = goals;
  }

  // read-only properties
  public string Name;
  {
     get
       { 
          return fullName;

   public string YearBorn;
  {
     get
       { 
          return yearBorn;
       }
  }

  public string Goals;
  {
     get
       { 
          return goalsPerGame;
       }
  }
```

In my second class FootballPlayerApp I am trying to get the user to enter firstly the number of players and secondly the details of all of those users.

I have created the following methods
    GetInput() //which allows the user to enter the number of players and   returns it
    GetName() //which allows the user to enter a players name
    GetYear() //which allows the user to enter the year born
    GetGoals() // which allows the user to enter the number of goals scored.

I understand that I can create a single object in the main method as follows

```
FootballPlayer player1 = new
FootballPlayer ("Lionel Messi", 1988, 2.3);
```

What I don't understand is

- how do I have the name of the object (e.g player1 in the example above) be different for each player the user enters when the user is able to enter any number of players.
- How do I loop it so that multiple players are entered until the numberOfPlayers is reached
- How do I display the results as follows.

e.g if the user entered 2 players
    player1 ("Lionel Messi", 1998, 2.3)
    player2 ("Ronaldo", 1985, 1.4)

how do I get the results to be displayed as

```
 Player Name    Year Born     Average Goals Scored

 Lionel Messi        1998                      2.3
 Ronaldo             1985                      1.4
```

Comment: Use a `for`-loop, create n-instances of `FootballPlayer` and add them to a `List<FootballPlayer>`. You can then access each player via index, for example player 10: `FootballPlayer playerTen = playerList[9];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I have the name of the object (e.g player1 in the example above) be different for each player

You don't.  Instead of individual variables, consider a *collection* of objects.  Basically, any time you find yourself trying to create `object1`, `object2`, `object3`, and so on then you *probably* want to use an array or collection of some kind instead.

This could be one of any number of collection types, even a simple array.  A common type to use in this case would be `List<T>`, which for your type would be `List<FootballPlayer>`.

Structurally it might look something like this:

```
var players = new List<FootballPlayer>();
var numberOfPlayers = GetInput();
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    // prompt the user to enter the next player

    var player = new FootballPlayer();
    player.Name = GetName();
    player.Goals = GetGoals();
    // etc.  Basically build up a FootballPlayer object from user input

    players.Add(player);
}
```

The user would be prompted for each player, and you can use the `i` variable within the loop to provide useful messages.  For example, "Enter the details for player 2:" or something like that.

After the loop is finished, you'd have a collection of `FootballPlayer` objects in the `players` variable.

Comment: how would I do this using an array?

Comment: @firepower4: Generally standard arrays don't allow re-sizing.  So you'd need the `numberOfPlayers` first and then declare the array based on that value.  The rest would be very similar though.  But instead of "adding" to the array (like one does with a `List<T>`), you'd be setting the object to an index in the array (which you can identify with the `i` value within the loop).

Comment: yeah that's essentially what I have actually done so far. Created three arrays where the length is equal to the numberOfPlayers.

I then used a while statement to get the user to enter info while counter < numberOfPlayers. From info entered assigned that to the appropriate index position in the array. I ended up with 3 arrays where an individual players info is in the same index positions.

Comment: @firepower4: Why do you need three arrays?  Is the user entering three *separate* lists of players?  The question makes it sound like the user is only entering one list of players.

Comment: my three arrays were a string array (which contained the names of all players), a int array (which contained the years born) and a double array (which contained the average goalse). 

Is it possible to put it all in one array?

Comment: @firepower4: Use an array of `FootballPlayer` objects. As an analogy, consider a parking lot full of cars. Which would make more sense... Putting each car into its own spot? Or having drivers disassemble their cars upon entering, put each component into the "spot" for those components (the "tires" spot, the "seats" spot, etc.), and then re-assembling when they leave? If what you want to store is a list of Football Players, then store a list of Football Players. Not multiple lists of values describing Football Players.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113751/discussion-between-firepower4-and-david).